# $.mobile.silentScroll does not work in worklight app

Tags: jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing an application using worklight framework from IBM in which I use jquery mobile library to code.

Unfortunately, when I use `$.mobile.silentScroll` to scroll, it has no effect, it does not work.

Has anyone met that issue? In other work, How to scroll page in worklight?

Comment: Provide a code snippet of your implementation and mention on which environment you are testing it.

Comment: I have copied the same piece of code as its api in http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.silentScroll/ into our worklight project, but it does not work!

Comment: Please answer my question fully.

Comment: I developed my app by the eclipse IDE with the installed worklight developer edition v.6.1 and just testing on an android device.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with jQuery Mobile's `silentScroll`, as it basically uses window.scrollTo, and this allows to scroll only within the current viewport (what you currently see on the screen).

Instead I would recommend to use [iScroll](http://iscrolljs.com/)'s various API methods: `scrollTo`, `ScrollToElement` or `Snap`, etc.

I tested the below in Android and it worked.
You'll of course need to adjust it to your application...

common\js\main.js:

```
var myScroll;

function wlCommonInit(){
    myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper');
}
```

common\index.html:

```
<body style="display: none;">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div data-role="page" id="page">
                <div data-role="content" id="content" style="padding: 15px">                
                    <div id="firstDiv">
                        <input type="button" value="scroll to the other div" onclick="myScroll.scrollToElement('#secondDiv', '0s');"/>
                    </div>
                    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                    <div id="secondDiv">
                        hello
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        ...
        ...
</body>
```

`0s` means there will be no scroll effect; it will essentially 'jump' to the desired location.